# Python 3: Tkinter frames and unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm currently trying to create a program in tkinter that has multiple screens, however I am running into a strange problem:when I try to raise a particular screen to the front, it doesnt appear. The code I use to create the differnt screens is this:

```
class PokemonDecklistCreatorApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (MainMenu, DecksMenu, DeckEditor, CardViewerDeckEditor,DeckNotes,SearchMenu, StandardSearch, AdvancedSearch, RandomSearch, SearchResults,CardViewerSearchResults, ExtrasMenu, CardExplanationGuide, AboutProgram):
            try:
                frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
                pageName = F.__name__
                self.frames[pageName] = frame
                frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
        self.show_frame('MainMenu')

    def show_frame(self, page):
        frame = self.frames[page]
        frame.tkraise()
```

Then the user can use the Search Screens to specify the criteria to search for, then the doSearch function is called which should destroy the old SearchResults screen (by popping from the self.frames dict and garbage collecting).

```
class RandomSearch(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.parent = parent
        [some widgety code here]
        self.btnSearch = tk.Button(self, text='Gotta Search \'em All!', command=self.doSearch, font=('Lucida Grande',24))
        self.btnSearch.place(x=450, y=670, width=500, height=40)

    def doSearch(self,* args,** kwargs):
        self.controller.frames.pop('SearchResults')
        frame=SearchResults(parent=self.parent,controller=self.controller,searchTerms=[])
        pageName = SearchResults.__name__
        self.controller.frames[pageName]=frame
        self.controller.show_frame('SearchResults')


class SearchResults(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller,searchTerms=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        [more widgety stuff]
```

However, the problem is that when I try running the doSearch function it creates the new object but doesn't display it. It remains on the same screen and I can still interact with it as usual, as if it didnt change scrreens at all!

I have checked the creation of new objects by putting `print(id(self.frames['SearchResults']))` in the show_frame function and it shows a different ID each time I press the button).

I also know that the problem is not with the `self.controller.show_frame('SearchResults')` line as I have tried `self.controller.show_frame('MainMenu')` and this worked as expected.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Could you provide a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please? I cannot run the code samples you provided and see the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
def doSearch(self,* args,** kwargs):
    ...
    frame=SearchResults...)
    pageName = SearchResults.__name__
    self.controller.frames[pageName]=frame
    self.controller.show_frame('SearchResults')
```

You never add the frame the the controller by calling `grid`. You likely need to add this statement:

```
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
```

I can't see any reason for needing to take a frame off of the list (without destroying it!) and putting a new one in its place. You've created a memory leak. Intead, you should just add a method in `SearchResults` that recreates or resets the widgets inside the existing `SearchResults` page.

Comment: @BrianOakley 
The point of destroying and recreating the frame is to pass new search terms to the object. I looked but found no way to pass variables to an object except to remake it, if you can offer a solution to that I'd be very grateful!

Comment: Actually don't worry about that last question, figured out a way round that! Since each object is passed the PokemonDecklistCreatorApp instance as a parameter (called controller) and that object has a dictionary in it called frames that contains instances of all the objects I can do `Variable = self.controller.frames['NameOfScreen'].AttributeToGet`